# Make speech marks bigger than rest of text on a Squarespace website

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I'm working on the [Squarespace](http://http:www.naomicambridge.squarespace.com)

At the bottom of the home page where there are testimonial quotations (with the pink background) I'd like to make the quotation marks bigger than the rest of the text.

I can see from going to inspect that the quotation marks are within the `<span></span>` tag.

If I add some custom CSS:

```
span {
  font-size: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px
}
```

Then I can get the quotation marks in around the size and position I want them, however it then creates a gap at the bottom between the last two lines of text, please see screenshot [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRXO7.jpg):

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I have accomplished this by placing the quotes in two `absolute` `divs` in a 3-column setup.  1st colum = opening quote. positioned `top:0; left0;`  --  Second column text  --  3rd column = closing quote positioned `bottom:0; right:0;`

Comment: Hi thank you for answering. I am still learning CSS, can you show me a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: Or just show me the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use pseudo-elements instead of `<span>`-s as follows:

```css
figure {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #eca29f;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: proxima-nova;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    letter-spacing: .015em;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    text-transform: none;
}
blockquote:before {
    content: "“";
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: 0.1em;
    margin-right: 0.1em;
    vertical-align: -0.4em;
}
blockquote:after {
    content: "”";
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: 0.1em;
    margin-right: 0.1em;
    vertical-align: -0.4em;
}
```

```html
<figure>
<blockquote>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</blockquote>
</figure>
```